# How to build a Monad with non-IO "exterior", but IO "interior"?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to write a Monad which renders some HTML, while tracking (and caching) a few specific function calls. Here's what I tried:

```hs
data TemplateM a = TemplateM
  { templateCache :: ![(Text, Text)]
  , templateResult :: !(IO a)
  }
```

Here's how I plan to use this:

```hs
renderCached :: Text -> TemplateM Text
renderCached k = 
  -- lookup templateCache from the monadic context, if it lacks the key, 
  -- then fetch the key from an external data source (which is where the
  -- "IO interior" comes from, and store it in templateCache (monadic context)
```

**Notably,** I do not want arbitrary `IO` actions to be executed in `TemplateM` via `lift`, `liftIO`, and suchlike. The only `IO` that should happen in `TemplateM` is to fetch something from the cache via the `renderCached` function.

I was able to define the `Functor` and `Applicative` instances for this, but got completely stuck with the `Monad` instance. Here's how far I got:

```hs
instance Functor TemplateM where
  {-# INLINE fmap #-}
  fmap fn tmpl = tmpl{templateResult=fmap fn (templateResult tmpl)}

instance Applicative TemplateM where
  {-# INLINE pure #-}
  pure x = TemplateM
    { templateCache = []
    , templateResult = pure x
    }

  {-# INLINE (<*>) #-}
  fn <*> f =
    let fnCache = templateCache fn
        fnFunction = templateResult fn
        fCache = templateCache f
        fResult = templateResult f
    in TemplateM { templateCache = fnCache <> fCache
                 , templateResult = fnFunction <*> fResult
                 }
```

**Is there any way to write the `Monad` instance for this without exposing the `IO` internals to the outside world?**

Comment: You don't need to worry about executing arbitrary IO actions just because you have an IO in your monad.  Just don't derive the `MonadIO` class (and don't export the `TemplateM` data constructor either) and you will be fine.

Comment: As for writing your monad instance, it might be instructive to try to articulate how you are stuck. It's not surprising to me that you can't write this instance -- the structure of your type is essentially a pair, so `Writer` is your inspiration.  But `WriterT` puts the pair *inside* the monad, not outside as you have done.  Also, since you intend to read from the cache, not just write it, Writer (aka pairing) will not support what you need.  Perhaps you need `StateT` ?

Comment: If you aren't yet comfortable with transformers, I would recommend trying to implement a state monad yourself `newtype State s a = State (s -> (a,s))`, with `get :: State s s` and `put :: s -> State s ()`, to get a feel for state-passing, and then come back to this, using what you learned about that pattern.

Comment: I agree with Luke. Your `TemplateM` has the cache as one of its members, meaning a monadic function `a -> TemplateM b` _returns_ the cache as an output. What you're looking for is a monad which takes the cache as an input (and possibly modifies it), namely `StateT`.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked out a solution sitting on top of `ReaderT`, but I really want to get my original idea to work:

```hs
newtype TemplateM a = TemplateM { unTemplateM :: ReaderT (IORef [(Text, Text)]) IO a } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

renderCached :: Text -> TemplateM Text
renderCached k = TemplateM $ do
  -- this is just dummy code. The actual cache lookup has not
  -- been implemented, but the types align
  v <- pure $ "rendered template for " <> k
  cacheRef <- ask
  atomicModifyIORef' cacheRef (\x -> ((k, v):x, ()))
  pure v

runTemplateM :: [(Text, Text)] 
             -> TemplateM a 
             -> IO ([(Text, Text)], a)
runTemplateM initialCache x = do
  initialCacheRef <- newIORef initialCache
  (flip runReaderT) initialCacheRef $ do
    res <- unTemplateM x
    ref <- ask
    finalCache <- readIORef ref
    pure (finalCache, res)
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested, the elementary solution here is to use `StateT`. Since you don't need to store your `IORef` in a data structure or share it between threads, you can eliminate it altogether. (Of course, if that changes and you *do* end up wanting to share state across multiple concurrent threads, you'll have to revisit this choice.)

```
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Tuple (swap)

newtype TemplateM a = TemplateM {unTemplateM :: StateT [(Text, Text)] IO a}
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

renderCached :: Text -> TemplateM Text
renderCached k = TemplateM $ do
  v <- pure $ "rendered template for " <> k
  modify ((k, v) :)
  pure v

runTemplateM :: [(Text, Text)]
             -> TemplateM a
             -> IO ([(Text, Text)], a)
runTemplateM initialCache x = fmap swap $ flip runStateT initialCache (unTemplateM x)
```

It goes without saying that a cache like this should almost certainly be stored as a structure that is not a list. One promising option is to use [text-trie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-trie), a data structure Wren Romano designed specially for this purpose. You might also consider a `HashMap` or even a `Map`.